# Is there a way to Live Project From View

Tags: uv, edit-mode

I'm trying to model from an image set as a background.
I have the camera and axis all lined up and I have a cube scaled to fit a building in the image. I Projected From View the front face of the building and it lines up well.
There is an overhang off the front of the building that I would like to extrude off the box and also project from view.

As soon as I modify the geometry the UVs start getting 'wonky' stretching and moving in relation to where loop-cuts were made etc.

Is there a way to have blender constantly projecting from view so that as I'm modeling I can see how the geometry is lining up an adjust accordingly.

[image: Screen Clip of Issue]

Ignore the portion off camera, I'll deal with that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sliding vertices, or making loop cuts, make sure that the Correct UV option is enabled.

[image]

As an alternative you can use the [UV project modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html), and use the camera as projector. That way the texture of the object will not change regardless of the geometry and the shape of the UVs. Once you are done editing the geometry you can make the projection permanent by applying the modifier.

The camera angle can be matched using the [BLAM add-on](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam). For more information see this post: [How can I recreate the floor using a photograph?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-the-floor-using-a-photograph/102750#102750)

[image]

Comment: I tried blam initially, and it just didn't work right. I used my phone to take the pictures, so the Focal Length is a relative known. BLAM came up with something crazy different, and nothing lined up.
Thanks for the info on keeping the UVs in place though.
This worked great for the loop/slide movements, but did not do what I was really hoping for which was a true live projection, when I went to do the extrusion it got wonky again. Maybe I'll try out the UV Project Modifier at some point, see if that does more of what I was looking for. Thanks