# How can I do anamorphose with blender?

Tags: camera

I every one, I'm wondering some can helping me, I want to create a wall anamorphose like Georges Rousse [image: utopia from Georges Rousse perfect point of view]

I just want to put a text in 360° in all the room project from the perfect center and after be able to print all the faces and glue it on the real one.

Thank's evrybody for helping me

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39565/text-on-a-balloon or

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106469/is-there-a-way-to-live-project-from-view/106473#106473

Comment: Or  maybe: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/camera-mapping-tutorial-v2