# problem projecting a photo onto a mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, fspy

I want to animate a quick shot of a road (photo) where my camera moves slightly.
So I'm trying to project a photo on a mesh on a simple "tunnel".

I've read this topic, [Project photo onto mesh UV texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141216/project-photo-onto-mesh-uv-texture), and I've built a scene setup using Fspy.
Once in Blender, it seems that everything is correct; my mesh does match the picture.

[image]

But once I unwrap my mesh, it doesn't work at all as expected :

[image]

Project is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptt9z2bke9gumex/unwrapTest.blend?dl=1) if you want to have a look at the file.

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: are normals inside? (control+shift+N to switch normal "inside")

Comment: How did you unwrap? Make sure you are looking through the camera and select U -> Project from view.

Comment: Hello :). The perspective seem to be a little extreme, perhaps [CGMatter can help](https://youtu.be/p9IfDeNU8K0) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the extreme perspective that forces high errors on simple geometry as mentioned by @jachymmichal.

One way is to add geometry to your cube before projecting UVs from view. Here is a way using the subdiv modifier:

[image]