# Tracking Problem with floor and wall and other things

Tags: modeling, video, tracking

I'm try to track a video with a garage.

I tracked the garage and the solve error is 0.11 because there is no movement, and now I want to model a sci-fi door that will be placed instead of the garage door.

The problem is when I set origin, the wall and floor and the other things like X and Y axis the placed content that will be made when I click on setup tracking scene is not in the right place.

When I click setup tracking scene a floor for the shadows and a cube will generated, and this floor should be on the ground of the garage video to catch shadows from the later modeled things, but I can't align it right.

How can I make it? I know I can rotate the camera self but I can't get it good.

And the second thing is  I want to make a sci-fi door and normally the set origin should be for the this. I tried it with tripod and then solve, then without it and set other scale but nothing helps.

Here is the file with the tracking, you only need to solve it:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0noe8i3mqa52ar/garage%20tracking%20june.blend1
https://www.dropbox.com/s/upt6gb516549mcr/garage%20tracking%20june.blend

Here is the file of the door:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g29m6aw7x0tnwpy/dooranimationneu.rar

Answer (score 0):

> I tracked the garage and the solve error is 0.11 because there is no movement

**If there is no motion there is no way to solve a scene**. You can't determine 3d information out of a still image.

3D reconstruction is based on calculating 3d space based on the movement of different elements across the frame. Moreover, only translation movement, (where the camera moves sideways or up down, not only rotation) is useful to recreate 3d data. Blender needs parallax information.

For situations like this use BLAM or Fspy.

Read:

[How can I recreate geometry using a photograph?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-geometry-using-a-photograph)

For a comprehensive post on motion tracking read:

[How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)