# Modelling a building from image that is not flat

Tags: modeling

I'm looking to create a 3D model of this building, but the only photo I have is the one attached. What is the best way to model the building if the photo isn't looking straight at the subject.[image]

Comment: You can use fSpy free software with fSpy Blender AddOn to have your camera match the X and Z vanishing points of the main surface.

Comment: [How can I recreate geometry using a photograph](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-geometry-using-a-photograph/102750#102750) In this particluar case use only the parallel lines in one of the sides of the building and the vertical lines\ in fSpy