# fSpy starting problems 2.8+?

Tags: add-on, installation, external-applications, fspy

I have downloaded and installed [fSpy](https://fspy.io/) for linux and installed the add-on but there is very little detail on how to run and use fspy as an app to import to linux as there is no proper tutorial or support data on this issue.

Does anyone have help for running this app for blender 2.8 onwards as I have 2.82?  Trying to do a tutorial and without it I can't do it.

Comment: *Right-click the Binary (AppImage) > Permissions > Allow executing file*... should work on all distros.

Comment: @brockmann this does not work as the only file with app is called app.tsx and this does nothing. This is in one of the gui folders.

Comment: Don't download the entire repository. You have download the *latest binary* from here: https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy/releases -> `fspy-1.0.3-x86_64.AppImage` (AppImage file) and the latest add-on for blender from here: https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases `fSpy-Blender-1.0.3.zip`

Comment: I have done so, it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download and install an add-on hosted on github properly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169234/how-to-download-and-install-an-add-on-hosted-on-github-properly)

Comment: the documentation is clear: https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender. Additionally read [How can I recreate geometry using a photograph?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-geometry-using-a-photograph/102750#102750)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't... download the entire repository.

- Download the latest **fspy binary** from here: [github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy/releases](http://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy/releases)
- And the latest **add-on** for blender from here: [github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases](http://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases).

[image]

*For Linux (AppImage):* *Right-click* (<kbd>RMB</kbd>) *the Binary > Permissions > Allow executing file*, which should work for all distros.

Further reading: [How to download and install an add-on hosted on github properly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169234/how-to-download-and-install-an-add-on-hosted-on-github-properly)