# How to write a text on a building picture

Tags: compositing-nodes

I would like to write a text/logo on one face of this building :

[image]

So I created some basic text (+ extrusion/bevel/...), but the problem is that I've no idea how I could reliably move this text (+shadows if possible) on a wall of this building (if possible I'd like to keep a good quality on the picture photo, so the picture should have the exact same shape at the end of the process). One simple solution would be to rotate approximately the text and then use gimp's perspective tool to move it on a face of the building, but I'm afraid to have only approximate perspective, and this may be visible on the final picture.

Someone proposed me to create planes first to reconstruct the shape of the building, and then add the text on the planes when it's done. But even after spending 10mn of trial/errors to find the good shape/position of the wall, focal length... I can't find a working set of parameters (one problem is that the shape of my initial picture is also changed due to the perspective):

[image]

What is the proper solution to that problem? Is there some automatic tools that can help me in that process?

Comment: Hello. Do you have any information about this building sizes?

Comment: Not really… I can try to check on the map if I can find the name of the building but there is no solution that is independant of that information?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found two plugins: fSpy and BLAM (this last one is outdated),  thanks to seseri, and intrac!

## Recommended solution: use fSpy

[fSpy](https://fspy.io/) is an external small software that you can download (Linux, Mac, Windows). Then you just have to place a few points on your picture to specify which are the aligned lined. Then, you need to save the project, and load it from the fSpy blender plugin (also need to be installed). The camera is automatically configured, and in my case it worked greatly! Just, I think the picture I gave above is not ideal, since I've the feeling that the building is not even a "cube": the higher you are, the fewer windows you have. So I just followed a line of window to find my parallel lines.

The package is well documented. In case you need more help, see [[this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSeBh5HdDVs)][2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSeBh5HdDVs) for example.

## Second solution, but outdated: BLAM

You may also be interested by [BLAM](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam) , but this plugin is outdated:

```
No longer maintained. Check out fSpy instead
```

You can find an example of use [here](https://youtu.be/yeWzQYh7iH0?t=146).

Comment: Read: [how can I recreate geometry using a photograph](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-geometry-using-a-photograph/102750#102750)